# Charles not working on iPhone at Starbucks

Tags: ios, network, proxy

I'm using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to sniff out the traffic on my iPhone at Starbucks and for some reason it won't work with `at&t wifi`. `Google Starbucks` wifi does, however. I use my iPhone to connect to the same wifi network that my MacBook is connected to. Then, for the proxy settings on my phone, I enter my computer's local IP address and the port that I specified in the proxy settings on Charles. I'm aware that some wifi networks block certain ports, but even when I change the proxy settings on Charles so that it's dynamic and it finds an open port, it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Client isolation.** It is your enemy and your friend here. This makes it so not only can you not access your iPhone from your MacBook, but other devices on the network cannot access your MacBook or your iPhone either. There are a number of ways to implement client isolation on an `IEEE 802.3` (Ethernet) network and even more ways on a `IEEE 802.11` (Wi-Fi) network, but they all essentially accomplish the same task - clients are only allowed to communicate with the access point and/or gateway.